# What does a column with plus sign mean in this Access 2003 table?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

It's from lesson. They create a field and then in the end result there is a column
with plus signs near that column. Can someone explain me what does that column with plus signs mean? And why I can't create it? I.e. how to create it?

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it with the "homework tag".  Including a screenshot would also be helpful.

Comment: No, this is not homework. Yes, I tried, but my points are insufficient to add screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plus sign means that there is a subdatasheet: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/add-a-subdatasheet-HA010266800.aspx